# C++ object name to str

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

...

map<string, House>  complexbook;

...

bool Complex::addHouse(const House &house) {
                                                  // v
    complexbook.insert(pair<const string, House>(to_string(house),house));   
    //return true if insert was succesful, return false if house already was in complexbook
}
```

So what I have a problem with is, how to create a string from the value of &house (as input for method). I want to do this because of return value of method - as described above, I want to differentiate between inserted and not inserted.

Comment: What do you want the hypothetical `to_string(house)` to return?

Comment: So create an `to_string` function to do what you need? [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is not a magic function that can take any kind of "object" and create a string from it.

Comment: If you want to know if insert was successful, `insert` method in `std::map` returns `std::pair` in which second element denotes whether the insertion took place or not

Comment: And is there some other, maybe better way, how to store object in set with some specific key? Maybe what would be the best type of that key?

Comment: What are the members of `House`? How do they distinguish unique houses? It could be as simple as `std::string to_string(const House & house) { return house.address; }`

Comment: Thank you. I have added new method for House. Now, how can I determine if insert was succesful or not? I'm trying it with iterator: `std::map<string,House>::iterator it = complexbook.find(houseName);`, but this code has error No viable overloaded '='.

Comment: @bartolomo `const_iterator` or better yet, you could have used `auto iter = …`

Comment: [std::map::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)